# Find Ids from multi dimensional object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, ecmascript-6

I have a multi dimensional object array:

```
var products = [  
{ id: 1, groups: [ { id: 1.1, selected: true }, { id: 1.2, selected: false }}, 
{ id: 2, groups: [ { id: 2.1, selected: false }, { id: 2.2, selected: true }} ];
```

How can I find list of selected groups (group with selected flag set to true) in a single dimensional array using ES6.

Expected Result:

```
[1.1, 2.2]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make use of `map`,`filter` and `concat` function and get result

```
var products = [  
{ id: 1, groups: [ { id: 1.1, selected: true }, { id: 1.3, selected: true },{ id: 1.2, selected: false }]}, 
{ id: 2, groups: [ { id: 2.1, selected: false }, { id: 2.2, selected: true }]} ];

const selectgroups =  [].concat(...products.map(x => x.groups.filter(g=> g.selected)));
const selectedGroupIds = selectgroups.map(g=> g.id);

console.log(selectedGroupIds);
```

code which provide list of all selected groups

[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/d34qt5Lc/)

Comment: and what is reason of - 1?... i answered late but i was help op from begining and based on input provided ...and deleted few answer as its downvoted based on old information

Answer (score 2):

You could use `reduce` method and inside one more `forEach` loop to get group objects where selected is `true`.

```js
var products = [  
{ id: 1, groups: [ { id: 1.1, selected: true }, { id: 1.2, selected: false }]}, 
{ id: 2, groups: [ { id: 2.1, selected: false }, { id: 2.2, selected: true }]} ];

const result = products.reduce((r, {groups}) => {
  groups.forEach(e => e.selected && r.push(e.id));
  return r;
}, [])
 
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

A possible alternative to all the other answers.

Flatten the array, then extract the required info.

```js
const products = [
    { id: 1, groups: [{ id: 1.1, selected: true }, { id: 1.2, selected: false }] },
    { id: 2, groups: [{ id: 2.1, selected: false }, { id: 2.2, selected: true }] }];

const allIds = [].concat(...products.map(p => p.groups)).filter(g => g.selected).map(x => x.id)

console.log(allIds)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use reduce and filter like below, this will give you all ids that have `selected: true`. Note that I changed id: 1.2 to be true to demonstrate the ability of getting multiple true results.

```js
const products = [
  { id: 1, groups: [ { id: 1.1, selected: true }, { id: 1.2, selected: true } ]},
  { id: 2, groups: [ { id: 2.1, selected: false }, { id: 2.2, selected: true } ]} ];

const res = products.reduce((a, {groups}) => 
  a.concat(...groups.filter(({selected}) => selected).map(({id}) => id))
, []);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var products = [  
{ id: 1, groups: [ { id: 1.1, selected: true }, { id: 1.2, selected: false }]}, 
{ id: 2, groups: [ { id: 2.1, selected: false }, { id: 2.2, selected: true } ]}];

var desiredResult = products.map(product => {
  return product.groups.filter(group => group.selected).map(item => item.id).toString();
});
console.log(desiredResult);
```

Comment: find won't work if you have multiple selected: true in an array

Comment: @developer updated answer for multi selected, used filter.

Answer (score 0):

I see a completely different approach: using specialized data structures to model the data the way you want to work with it:

```js
// Store product id mapped to a set of
// group ids
const productGroupMap = new Map ( [
   [ 1, new Set ( [ 1.1, 1.2 ] ) ],
   [ 2, new Set ( [ 2.1, 2.2 ] ) ]
] )

// Store group ids to their data
const groupMap = new Map ( [
   [ 1.1, { title: "Title 1.1" } ],
   [ 1.2, { title: "Title 1.2" } ],
   [ 2.1, { title: "Title 2.1" } ],
   [ 2.2, { title: "Title 2.2" } ]
] )

// Somewhere in your application, you would declare
// a set of selected group ids, and you would add ids
// when the user selects a given group
const selectedGroups = new Set ()

selectedGroups.add ( 1.1 )
selectedGroups.add ( 2.2 )

// Finally, when you want these selected groups, you just need to
// map selected group ids to their group data getting it from the
// groupMap
const groups = [ ...selectedGroups ].map ( id => groupMap.get ( id ) )

console.log ( groups )
```